Error when trying to use 'platform login' command in Platform.sh
I'm trying to use platform.sh in my python virtual environment, but when I try to run platform login in a command prompt to login, it will not work. The login browser page does open and says I logged in successfully, but the command prompt says:

[RequestException] cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Here is the full output of the command prompt:
(ll_env) C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\learning_log>platform login
Opened URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000
Please use the browser to log in.

Help:
  Leave this command running during login.
  If you need to quit, use Ctrl+C.

Login information received. Verifying...


  [RequestException]
  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I tried quite a few things. I downloaded cacert.pem and set it up, and I also asked ChatGPT, who had no clue on what was going on. It kept presenting solutions that would do nothing to help.

There are several different reasons this can occur. However, trying to work through all of them is too much to cover here. Your fastest option is to open a support ticket with platform.sh or alternatively, asking in their community site: https://community.platform.sh/
